# Apply a circular shift to an ORDER BY query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weekly timeline on mysql wherein I sort activities by time using the built-in `ORDER BY` function: `ORDER BY time`.

### Actual result

```
00:01
07:00
08:00
11:00
23:00
```

### Expected result

```
07:00
08:00
11:00
23:00
00:01
01:00
04:00
```

etc., 'til 07:00 (e.g., modulus 7 a.m.).

How can I change the format?

Comment: Your desired results make no sense

Comment: This is why we store datetimes in 24 hour time format

Comment: simply store date time and apply order by ....

Comment: Unless you have a date field associated with time field, you can't get the said desired solution.

Comment: @John Conde He's trying to do a modulus shift on his ORDER BY query.  He wants to start from 7 a.m. (probably the beginning of the work day).

Comment: I think you're looking for psychicSQL

Comment: @Strawberry, aw.... come-on... I've seen some other creative queries you've written in the past, but I do like the thought of "psychicSQL" :)

Answer (score 1):

What it appears is you want the rotation based on 7:00am - 6:59am.  You could just do an order by based on if the time is BEFORE 7am, force a pre-sort to 2... if 7am or AFTER, pre-sort is 1, then sort by the natural time...

```
order by
   case when hour( columnTime ) < 7 then 2 else 1 end,
   columntime
```

this way if your time samples were

```
00:01a
02:27a
05:42a
06:59a
07:00a
10:29a
02:27p
11:59p
```

The presort would result like...

```
PRESORT  Time
1        07:00a
1        10:29a
1        02:27p
1        11:59p
2        00:01a
2        02:27a
2        05:42a
2        06:59a
```

updated via [SQLFiddle adjusted](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38867/5).  The function HOUR() returns the numeric our of a date/time column. You had HOURS().  Now, the parameter to the function is the name of the column that holds the date/time field.  I didn't have your table structure to KNOW the column name so I just called it "columnTime".  Per the SQLFiddle sample you had, I changed it to...

HOUR( hours ) <-- HOUR() function, using your column "hours" from the table

Comment: DRapp But can you also show working code (a full, functioning example)?  For example, I tried this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38867/2.  I altered it in a few ways, but I wasn't able to create a successful query.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, see revision and SQLFiddle revision too

Comment: I think this is the answer.  I didn't think to use a singular form of the column name there.  It's actually difficult syntactically because hours is non-count: `0001 hours`.  Thanks for the update.  I'll put it in my codebook.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe looking for this ?

```
  ORDER BY str_to_date(columntime,'%H:%i')
```

or this

```
 ORDER BY  MINUTE(columntime) , SECOND(columntime)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495513/4)

EDIT:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN HOUR(date_time) BETWEEN 7 AND  12
   THEN 2
    else 1
end desc ,date_time asc
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4179/13)

Comment: This is not going to work if time is in `24` hour format. You have to use `'%H:%i'`. See Demo @ http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46b660/1

Comment: So, can one of you show an sqlfiddle that takes a 24-hour clock with queries starting at 7 a.m. and ending at 12 a.m.  Then, query the results such that the results begin at 7 a.m. and end at 6:59 a.m.?  The top-most query should be 7 a.m., and the bottom-most query should be 6:59 a.m.

Comment: aside from your edite was almost identical concept as my original answer, you are only considering a 5 hour window as the hour function regardless returns based on a 24-hour clock...  Your second demo is still incorrect.